# How can I access my company's emails externally at home using outlook?

Tags: email, imap, pop3, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-client

I don't have any knowledge about email servers like IMAP, POP3 etc. We can access our emails on LAN in office using internal LAN url and also using outlook. At home, I can access it through another external IP address url via browser interface. I want to know whether using this external IP address url, can I access my emails using outlook also at home ?

Comment: This looks like a superuser.com question

Comment: Unless you're writing a program to access the email, this is off topic.

Comment: Talk to your company's IT department.

Comment: I agree with ChrisF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consult someone at work to see if this is possible. Some companies block the ability to access information (including email) outside of the building.

If you ask someone in IT or a Manager, etc they should be able to set it up for you or give you directions on how your work from home system works.